# Vuetify 3 Combobox: How to get the id of selected item with same item name?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

How do I get the id of the selected item in a vuetify 3 combobox when the item names are the same?

I could search the Items array for the same name with the `searchedText` `v-model`, but it doesn't work in this case. So, how I get the unique id?

An example Array:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Same Name"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Same Name"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Same Name"
  }
]
```

The Combobox:

```
<v-combobox
    v-model="searchedText"
    label="Search..."
    :items="items.map((e) => { return e.name; })"
    @update:menu="test()"
></v-combobox>
```

I´ve created an example on vuetify play: [Link](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

I really have no idea how i could manage this... . I should be able to figure out which select I clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

The `v-compobox` does work with objects about the same way as `v-select`

It gives back the selected object. You can then get values from the object.

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main class="mx-5">
      <h2 class=my-4>
        How to get the id of selected item with same item name?
      </h2>
      <v-combobox
        v-model="searchedItem"
        label="Search..."
        :items="items"
        item-title="name"
        item-value="id"
        variant="solo"
        class="pa-1"
        @update:menu="test()"
    ></v-combobox>
      -> searchedItem: {{searchedItem}}<br/>
      -> Id: {{selectedId}}<br/>
      -> Name: {{selectedName}}<br/>
      <pre>{{items}}</pre>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'

const searchedItem = ref(null)

const selectedId = computed(() => { return searchedItem.value?.id })
const selectedName = computed(() => { return searchedItem.value?.name })
```

[Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqdVE1T2zAQ/SsaXQgzsUSAXjIm0Fu59NIj5qDYClaxJY0kBxiP/3t3JYc4SVsGTtbq7b79evJDT79by7adpEuaB9naRgS5KjQh+TYT1sZjNFqhNCkb4f1NQdvX7FtBRxDg+nKE2rfs+v2akB/mhQRDnmQgoZZEVcRsiJeNLIOsiIKE5EWFmnjRAoqmhtPtOy+vL/dJtllp2rVZm9d9AqjLVLKBkrwUrqxldQ8sBd17NGId8V8RZ4xNwSXmxIbid4rgRRZUaCSgWNQJuBVNh6CqptBWOCV0wIJMY6bIbnZWZIvp/V1nKxj6spW6AzhIH2bnO4dVzvdtv48iW8EQ9+0uSd9P7WHI145Pve+r5JMGf1+devyEFqc+aB955dbJVd/HUQHE0RzlAUWiPpJwwEjKyflEUWD60ikboPTQIaxaa1wgPXFyMyfQpO1QFQPZONOSMxDlGYaVRnsM2vdHbjBkprumOZ967LoDfMc2m52Tm1XMETqnD2hY3OAtA1UOwHPIgv1/kgdVEpl2XHFSY7EPOJo+jUvBNhbzdMagJQF5YjAmTZsfIjzxv/yk/9UH/oV+jJVuOl0GZTRJuksUnJP6Sy+30ECc87RoWDGd07RlkIdlv73R8J+JKeDdRAAeHcgu1VpQ2DnaBa1DsH7Jeaft8xODLfA7wLjrdFCtzCrT3l2xK3aRicbWgl3zSvkwhZn0bbZ25sVLB4kLOs4j5ghq8/avPCMM9Au2uEi8410G/xKPxCeEHLJspcuc1JV00v23iSPfvzVy5HLSzLjCAebbKP3sj0Zb+jjWqDm0v9BlpMD4R0wzzOlBlZA3RdLHPzh7Bec=) with the `v-compobox`

---

Use [`<v-select>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/) instead of [`<v-combobox>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox/)

```
     <v-select
        v-model="searchedText"
        label="Search..."
        :items="items"
        item-title="name"
        item-value="id"
        variant="solo"
        class="pa-1"
        @update:menu="test()"
    ></v-select>
```

Here is the updated [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: A `v-select` behaves differently than a `combobox`. I don't need a dropdown, but a text field where the user can search for a term like with Google.

Comment: Thanks for your update, works perfectly. But in my environment, with the same snippet, I have to click two times into the text-field before the suggestions appears. That´s the reason why i'm discard to use `item-value`... do you have an idea, where this behavior came from?

Comment: No, I have no idea. You could try to change the version of Vuetify.

Comment: Sometimes it is so easy... an update to the newest version of vuetify works. Thanks @Tolbxela